# Python encapsulation via mangling working, but confused about assignments to attributes from outside the class

Tags: python, encapsulation, name-mangling

I cannot get my head around what is happening here.
I create my class and use double underscore to mangle the names so that it works as a manner of encapsulation, I create an instance of an object and I have get methods to access them and then I try to set them from outside the class and it looks like instead of attempting to modify the attributes and failing, python is creating new variables, external to the object, that have the same name as the attributes of the object.

Is that what is happening? If not, what?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, __name, __position):
    self.__name = __name
    self.__position = __position

    def talk(self, aStatement):
        print(aStatement)
    def walk(self, aPosition):
        self.__position = aPosition
    def getPosition(self):
        return self.__position
    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

person1 = Person("Mr. Table", ["Room 115", [13, 20]])
print(person1.getPosition())
person1.walk(["Room 117", [0, 0]])
print(person1.getPosition())
person1.name = "Pedro"
person1.position = ["Room XXX", [13, 20]]
print(person1.name)
print(person1.getName())
print(person1.position)
print(person1.getPosition())
```

Comment: Please verify that your code is as intended and properly indented. As is, your __init__ function will throw an error.

Comment: And, as an aside, `person1.name` will set a new attribute "name" on "person1". You might want to go look at example of using `@property` as a decorator in order to make these pseudo-private variables that can only be got and not set. Also, including `print` statements without saying what they print is useless for people reading your post.

Answer (score 0):

Python's name mangling is very simple It transforms `self.__name` into `self.__Person_name` when used in the `Person` class (when used in other classes it uses those other class's names instead of `Person`).

Name mangling is intended to help you avoid accidental name conflicts, especially for mixin classes that can't know in advance what other attributes will exist on their instances.

It's not really intended for encapsulation or making variables "private". Python's designers generally don't think that's very useful. The way to avoid other programmers using your class in the wrong way is to document your code well, not to declare things private or jump through a bunch of hoops to lock them out.

If you really do want to control the access to attributes on your class, consider using `property` (to control assignment to a single attribute) or `__setattr__` (to control assignment to all attributes of a class). Often though it's not necessary to prevent attribute assignments, as long as the documentation clearly states what attributes are part of the public API (and what values are acceptable for each). If you find a clear need to validate the value of a specific attribute after the API is being used, you can still go back and turn it into a `property` after the fact. (The inability to refactor attribute access is the main reason other languages like C++ and Java tend to say you should always use getter and setter methods instead.)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the backing store of Python instances are dictionaries, which can be manipulated pretty much like, well dictionaries.  You can get or set any property you want and add new ones.  To limit this free-for-all a bit, you can use decorators to designate your accessors:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, position):
        self.__name = name
        self.__position = position

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self.__position

    @position.setter
    def position(self, aPosition):
        self.__position = aPosition

person1 = Person("Mr. Table", ["Room 115", [13, 20]])
print(person1.position)
person1.position = ["Room 117", [0, 0]]
print(person1.position)
person1.name = "Pedro"  # this will crash the code as it's "readonly"
person1.position = ["Room XXX", [13, 20]]
print(person1.name)
print(person1.position)
```

Although we'd expect the accessor person1.position(), it is now person1.person which can be evaluated or set.  The decorator functions set this up for you.  It looks like a simple property but there's actually code behind it.  Since we didn't include a setter for 'name', you can access it via person1.name but you can't set it that way.

You might read about `__slots__` and be tempted to use it to limit access to the underlying backing store.  This feature is really only for space savings on classes with huge numbers of instances and trying to use it to constrain the behavior of your object will only lead to tears.